# Symfony2 Redirection for unauthorised page with access_denied_url

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the `access_denied_url`parameter in `security.yml`

The problem is that... it does nothing. When I access to `/mon-equipement` as anonymous, it keeps redirecting me to `/login`

Here is my `security.yml`file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider


                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /mon-equipement
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            access_denied_url: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/mon-equipement, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I'm using FOSUserBundle with Symfony2.3.16

Comment: I am having same issue. could you please let me know how you fixed it. thks.

Comment: I didn't find a solution.
I stopped searching... "Deal with it"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to know that *access_denied_url* is only redirecting non anonymous users. For instance it will redirecte a user with ROLE_MEMBER if it tries to acces a page whose path is only for ROLE_ADMIN.

Here the solution:
You have to create a service (**my_entry_point**) that will be triggered at the **entry-point** listener (see security.yml below) and which will redirect the user to the page you want (**target_page_for_redirection**)

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
  firewalls:
    main:
      entry_point: my_entry_point  # listener triggered if no token is set while an authentification is needed (access_control)
      pattern:  ^/
```

.

```
#src/Acme/UserBundle/Ressources/Config/services.yml

service
  my_entry_point:
     class: Acme\UserBundle\Redirection\EntryPointRedirection
     arguments: [@router] #needed for URL redirection
```

.

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Redirection;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class EntryPointRedirection implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
   protected $router;

   public function __construct($router)
   {
      $this->router = $router;
   }

   public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
   {
      return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('target_page_for_redirection'));
   }
}
```

Comment: Good job, I was not aware that the `access_denied_url` parameter is only redirecting non anonymous users.

Answer (score 4):

I think your `access_controll` section should looks like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # ... here the other routes
```

**Your problem:** It redirects you on the `/` page, but you have no access to this page. Therefore it redirects you on the login page.

**UPDATE:**

You can also define `access_denied_url` for all firewalls:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    access_denied_url: /
```

Comment: I've tried it before and it changes nothings. I also tried to clear the cache, for what it's worth.

Comment: @LaurentWartel You have tried `path: ^/.*` or `path: ^/$`?

Comment: I've tried `^/$` and `^/`. Also, applying the `access_denied_url` at `security` level doensn't work (I've tested before). I'm starting to believe that the parameter may be overrided somewhere...

Comment: access_denied_url only works for non anonymous users.