# How to replace all 403 status codes with 404 in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, security, permissions

In Symfony, when a user attempts to access a route which is forbidden for that specific user (according to the user roles), a page with response code 403 will be returned.

So the user can still see that there is a valid route there.

I would like to overwrite this behavior by replacing the status code 403 with 404, so the user will just see that there is no valid route when she/he is not allowed to access that resource.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: you need to check this link for exception handling http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a simpler solution: using an **access denied handler**.

Unfortunately there is no much documentation about how to create an access denied handler, but it is very simple.

First create a class that implements the [AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authorization/AccessDeniedHandlerInterface.html) and set it as a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) (for example naming it `my_access_denied_handler_service`).

In the `handle` method a [Response](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) should be created and returned (in my case I wanted a 404 response).

Then in the `security.yml` configuration file we have to set the `access_denied_handler` under the `firewall`:

```
...
firewalls:
    my_firewall:
        ...
        access_denied_handler: my_access_denied_handler_service
        ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is doable, however almost undocumented. I'm aware of two ways but there might be even more:

- Using `access_denied_url` configuration option. See [security config reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html). With this option you can set URL where the user is redirected when the user in unauthorized (I think it should work also with route name). See a similar question: [Symfony2 Redirection for unauthorised page with access_denied_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762546/symfony2-redirection-for-unauthorised-page-with-access-denied-url)
- There're also "Entry Points" as mentioned in [The Firewall and Authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points). However, no examples, no explanation how to use it.

  I looks like this option expects a service name as can be seen in [security config reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) (search for `entry_point` option).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, as partially explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller), can be the following:

1) Defining a new service controller in `services.yml`

```
exception_controller:
      class: Path\To\MyBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
      arguments: ['@twig', '%kernel.debug%']
```

2) Creating the new class which overrides `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController`:

```
namespace Path\To\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyExceptionController extends ExceptionController
{
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering($request->headers->get('X-Php-Ob-Level', -1));
        $showException = $request->attributes->get('showException', $this->debug); // As opposed to an additional parameter, this maintains BC

        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();

        if ($code == 403) {
            $code = 404;

            // other customizations ...
        }

        return new Response($this->twig->render(
            (string) $this->findTemplate($request, $request->getRequestFormat(), $code, $showException),
            array(
                'status_code' => $code,
                'status_text' => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
                'exception' => $exception,
                'logger' => $logger,
                'currentContent' => $currentContent,
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

3) Setting the following in `config.yml` under `twig`:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: 'exception_controller:showAction'
```

Even though my original goal was to prevent such an exception to be thrown at all with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be overwriting the `AccessListener` service of the Symfony Security component.

The generic procedure about how to override a service of a bundle is documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/override.html#services-configuration). The following is the concrete example about this particular situation.

First of all let's create the class which overrides the `AccessListener` class:

```
<?php

namespace Path\To\My\Bundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class OverrideAccessListener extends AccessListener
{
    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        try {
            parent::handle($event);
        } catch (AccessDeniedException $e) {

            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $message = sprintf('No route found for "%s %s"', $request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo());

            if ($referer = $request->headers->get('referer')) {
                $message .= sprintf(' (from "%s")', $referer);
            }

            throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
        }
    }
}
```

then we need to create a **Compiler Pass** in order to change the class attribute of the original service with the new class:

```
<?php

namespace Path\To\My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('security.access_listener');
        $definition->setClass('Path\To\My\Bundle\Services\OverrideAccessListener');
    }
}
```

finally we need to [register the Compiler Pass in the build method of the bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/compiler_passes.html):

```
<?php

namespace Path\To\My\Bundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Path\To\My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class MyBundleName extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```